# KonvaJS - Rotate rectangle around cursor without using offset

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I am using KonvaJS to drag and drop rectangles into predefined slots.  Some of the slots need to be rotated 90 degrees.  I have a hit box around the slots that are rotated vertically, so when the user drags the rectangle into the area it will rotate 90 degrees automatically (to match the orientation).  When it rotates, it moves out from under the mouse.  This can be solved with offset, but then the rectangle doesn't visually line up with the boxes after snapping.  This can (probably) be solved with additional code.

I have tried to rotate the rectangle, and then move it under the mouse.  Since the user is still dragging it, this doesn't seem to work as I planned.

**Is it possible to force the rectangle to rotate under the mouse without using offset?**

Here is a fiddle showing the issue - The offset problems can be demonstrated by setting the first variable to true. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ChaseRains/1k0aqs2j/78/

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var rectangleLayer = new Konva.Layer();
var holdingSlotsLayer = new Konva.Layer();
var controlLayer = new Konva.Layer();
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height,
  draggable: true
});
//vertical holding spot
holdingSlotsLayer.add(new Konva.Rect({
  x: 300,
  y: 25,
  width: 130,
  height: 25,
  fill: '#fff',
  draggable: false,
  rotation: 90,
  stroke: '#000'
}));

//horizontal holding spot
holdingSlotsLayer.add(new Konva.Rect({
  x: 25,
  y: 75,
  width: 130,
  height: 25,
  fill: '#fff',
  draggable: false,
  rotation: 0,
  stroke: '#000'
}));

//mask to set boundaries around where we wannt to flip the rectangle
controlLayer.add(new Konva.Rect({
  x: 215,
  y: 15,
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  fill: '#fff',
  draggable: false,
  name: 'A',
  opacity: 0.5
}));
stage.add(holdingSlotsLayer, controlLayer);

//function for finding intersections
function haveIntersection(placeHolder, rectangle, zone) {
  if (rectangle.rotation == 0 || zone == true) {
    return !(
      rectangle.x > placeHolder.x + placeHolder.width ||
      rectangle.x + rectangle.width < placeHolder.x ||
      rectangle.y > placeHolder.y + placeHolder.height ||
      rectangle.y + rectangle.height < placeHolder.y
    );
  } else {
    return !(
      rectangle.x > placeHolder.x + 25 ||
      rectangle.x + rectangle.width < placeHolder.x ||
      rectangle.y > placeHolder.y + placeHolder.height + 90 ||
      rectangle.y + rectangle.height < placeHolder.y
    );
  }
}

//function to create rectangle group (so we can place text on the rectangle)
function spawnRectangle(angle) {
  var rectangleGroup = new Konva.Group({
    x: 95,
    y: 95,
    width: 130,
    height: 25,
    rotation: angle,
    draggable: true,
  });

  rectangleGroup.add(new Konva.Rect({
    width: 130,
    height: 25,
    fill: 'lightblue'
  }));

  rectangleGroup.add(new Konva.Text({
    text: '123',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fill: '#000',
    width: 130,
    padding: 5,
    align: 'center'
  }));

  //function tied to an on drag move event
  rectangleGroup.on('dragmove', (e) => {
    //shrink rectangle hitbox for use in placeholder intersection
    var dimensions = {
      "height": 3,
      "width": 5,
      "x": e.target.attrs.x,
      "y": e.target.attrs.y,
      'rotation': e.target.attrs.rotation
    };
    //loop over holding slots to see if there is an intersection.
    for (var i = 0; holdingSlotsLayer.children.length > i; i++) {
      //if true, change the look of the slot we are hovering
      if (haveIntersection(holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs, dimensions, false)) {
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.fill = '#C41230';
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.dash = [10, 3];
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.stroke = '#000';
        //set attributes back to normal otherwise
      } else {
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.fill = '#fff';
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.dash = null;
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.stroke = null;
      }
    }

    //check to see if we are in a zone that requires the rectangle to be flipped 90 degrees 
    if (haveIntersection(controlLayer.children[0].attrs, dimensions, true)) {
      if (rectangleGroup.attrs.rotation != 90) {
        rectangleGroup.attrs.rotation = 90;
      }
    } else {
      rectangleGroup.attrs.rotation = 0;
    }

    stage.batchDraw();
  });

  rectangleGroup.on('dragend', (e) => {

    for (var i = 0; holdingSlotsLayer.children.length > i; i++) {
      //If the parking layer has an element that is lit up, then snap to position.. 
      if (holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.fill == '#C41230') {
        rectangleGroup.position({
          x: holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.x,
          y: holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.y
        });
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.fill = '#fff';
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.dash = null;
        holdingSlotsLayer.children[i].attrs.stroke = null;
      }
    }

    stage.batchDraw();
  });


  rectangleLayer.add(rectangleGroup);
  stage.add(rectangleLayer);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  background-size: cover;
}

#desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.0.18/konva.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="desc">
    <button onclick="spawnRectangle(0)">spawn rectangle</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could move the group offset to the mouse position in a mousedown even. The offset is the rotation point.  Then when the rotation is applied it would make the rectangle rotate around the mouse. You would probably have to account for the position change in your overlap code.  PS. A very well presented question.

Comment: Haha - just re-read the question and note the request for no offset! So, what else can you do...well life's a rectangle in canvas land so to get the same effect you need to calculate vector from the mouse pointer at the point in time that rotation is to happen then work out the vector by which to move the rectangle's origin after rotation. It's just math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function to rotate the rectangle under the mouse, without using konva offset(). I used a tween to apply the movement but if you prefer to use it without the tween just apply the rect.rotate() then apply the newPos x & y as the position.

EDIT: The OP pointed out that if you clicked, held the mouse down whilst the rectangle completed its animation, then dragged, then the rectangle would jump away. What gives ? Well, when the mousedown event runs Konva takes note of the shape's initial position in its internal drag function. Then when we start to actually drag the mouse, Konva dutifully redraws the shape in the position it calculates. Now, 'we' know that we moved the shape in out code, but we didn't let Konva in on our trick.

The fix is to call

```
 rect.stopDrag(); 
 rect.startDrag();
```

immediately after the new position has been set. Because I am using a tween I do this in the onFinish() callback function of one of the tweens - you would want to ensure its the final tween if you apply more than one. I got away with it because my tweens run over the same period. If you aren't using tweens, just call the above immediately you apply your last rotate() or position() call on the shape.

```js
function rotateUnderMouse(){


  // Get the stage position of the mouse
  var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();

  // get the stage position of the mouse
  var shapePos = rect.position();

  // compute the vector for the difference
  var rel = {x: mousePos.x - shapePos.x, y: mousePos.y - shapePos.y} 

  // Now apply the rotation
  angle = angle + 90;


  // and reposition the shape to keep the same point in the shape under the mouse 
  var newPos = ({x: mousePos.x  + rel.y , y: mousePos.y - rel.x}) 

  // Just for fun, a tween to apply the move: See https://konvajs.org/docs/tweens/Linear_Easing.html
  var tween1 = new Konva.Tween({
    node: rect,
    duration: 0.25,
    x:  newPos.x,
    y: newPos.y,
    easing: Konva.Easings.Linear,
    onFinish: function() { rect.stopDrag(); rect.startDrag();}
  });
  
  // and a tween to apply the rotation 
  tween2 = new Konva.Tween({
    node: rect,
    duration: 0.25,
    rotation: angle,
    easing: Konva.Easings.Linear
  });
    
  
  tween2.play();
  tween1.play();


  
}


function setup() {

// Set up a stage and a shape
stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'canvas-container',
  width: 650,
  height: 300
});


layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

newPos = {x: 80, y: 40};
rect = new Konva.Rect({
   width: 140, height: 50, x: newPos.x, y: newPos.y, draggable: true, stroke: 'cyan', fill: 'cyan'
  })
layer.add(rect);

stage.draw()

rect.on('mousedown', function(){
  rotateUnderMouse()
})

}

var stage, layer, rect, angle = 0;

setup()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/4.0.13/konva.js"></script>

<p>Click the rectangle - it will rotate under the mouse.</p>

<div id="canvas-container"></div>
```